# How to prevent the browser from redirecting when a redirect response is sent via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, redirect

I'm trying to AJAX-ify the Django contact_form app using Django (1.4.2).  I want to let Django do the heavy lifting when it comes to validation and template rendering so I can keep my templates consistent and server side.  Therefore, I'm returning "partial" template renderings to inject into the DOM as the user submits the form.

It *almost* works; The form submits, the partial template renders and is returned, validation errors are displayed, etc.  However, once the form is valid, the contact_form's view does an http redirect.  I've set the `success_url` to redirect to *just* the sent message url.

I expected it to redirect on the server, return the sent message and replace the form with it.  However, this *only* worked correctly in Chrome.  In Firefox and IE the entire browser redirects to my sent message url.

Is there any way to get the redirects to **only** affect the AJAX response and not redirect the entire browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as far not possible. FF and IE are behaving correctly as per the W3 specification.

Here's an extract of chapter 4.6.4 of the [W3 `XMLHttpRequest` specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest):

> ### [4.6.4. Infrastructure for the send() method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send-method)
>
> - If the response is an HTTP redirect
>
>   If the redirect does not violate security (it is [same origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#same-origin) for instance), infinite loop precautions, and the scheme is supported, **transparently follow the redirect** while observing the [same-origin request event rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#same-origin-request-event-rules).

A HTTP redirect basically instructs the client side to fire a brand new HTTP GET request to the given location. Your best bet is to instead do a **server-side** *include* or *forward* to the desired resource.

Alternatively you can also let it instead return some JSON which should notify your jQuery code in some callback function that it should re-fire a new ajaxical request on the URL as returned by the JSON.

It's however a future consideration to add a property to disable following redirects. Here's another extract:

> ### [Not in this Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#notcovered)
>
> This specification does not include the following features which are being considered for a future version of this specification:
>
> - Property to disable following redirects;

Comment: So much for wrapping the views then, it looks like I'll simply have to rewrite them.